# How to center the action with CardHeader title in Material-UI for React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to achieve the actions (Edit & Delete) to align vertically centered on the CardHeader. As shown in the screenshot, the buttons are not aligned with the title & avatar of CardHeader. The avatar seems to align center vertically when the content of the title requires two or more lines to show, but the actions stay in the top right corner.

I would really appreciate any help from the community.

[image]

Here is my code snippet

```
<CardHeader
    avatar={
        <Avatar className={classes.avatarNumber}>
            <Typography variant={"h5"}>Q</Typography>
        </Avatar>
    }
    title={<Typography variant={"h6"}>Gelloo</Typography>}
    action={
        <Box>
            <IconButton>
                <DeleteIcon/>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton>
                <EditIcon/>
            </IconButton>
        </Box>
    }
/>
```

Added new:
A possible solution to override the MuiCardHeader-action. But if there is any better solution, please suggest me. Thanks!

```
overrides: {
    MuiCardHeader: {
        action: {
            marginTop: "auto",
            marginBottom: "auto"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you show me the MuiCardHeader-root style?, maybe just adding align-item: center to it will fix

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I updated the question with a possible solution. Do you think it is optimum?

Comment: try adding stying to the Box, with display flex, alignItems:center

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can straight away use `CardHeader` `props` of:-

- `classes`: to apply changes to `root` of `CardHeader` (we can apply `action` style too from here)
- `titleTypographyProps`: to apply any styles to the **title**
- `subheaderTypographyProps`: to apply any styles to the **subTitle**
- use `makeStyles` from `@material-ui/core/styles` and override them using `classes` instead of doing manually using `withStyles` override (this is more neat and clean)
- `example.js`:-

```js
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const Demo = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (
    <CardHeader
      avatar={
        <Avatar className={classes.avatarNumber}>
          <Typography variant={"h5"}>Q</Typography>
        </Avatar>
      }
      title={<Typography variant={"h6"}>Gelloo</Typography>}
      action={
        <Box>
          <IconButton>
            <DeleteIcon/>
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton>
            <EditIcon/>
          </IconButton>
        </Box>
      }
      classes={{
        root: classes.cardHeaderRoot,
        action: classes.cardHeaderAction
      }}
      titleTypographyProps={{
        classes: {
          root: classes.cardHeaderTitleRoot
        }
      }}
      subheaderTypographyProps={{
        classes: {
          root: classes.cardHeaderSubTitleRoot
        }
      }}
    />
  )
}
export default Demo

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  cardHeaderRoot: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[400]
  },
  cardHeaderAction: {
    margin: "auto"
  },
  cardHeaderTitleRoot: {
    color: theme.palette.error.main,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  cardHeaderSubTitleRoot: {
    color: theme.palette.error.main,
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
}));
```

You can see this working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-ishizaka-onm1k?file=/src/App.js) to try the live version.

Comment: I checked your sandbox code, I think you misunderstood my question. It center-aligns the title and subtitle, not the action menu icon button, the menu button still stays at the top right corner even if you have, for example, a title with 200 words. The menu button should align-center as I have added a screenshot later in my question.

Comment: The same **concept** being applied for centering the `action` part too. I've **updated** my **code** above & the **sandbox**

Comment: Thanks for your help, I checked your code. It is because the margin set to auto in the action allowed the action menu button to center.